# Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a function that returns a **Promise**

```
  function superHero_with_name (name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var encoded_superhero_name = name.split(" ").join("%20");
        var path_superhero = '/api.php/' + superhero_access_token + '/search/' + encoded_superhero_name ;
        console.log('API Request: ' + host_superhero + path_superhero);

        http.get({host: host_superhero, path: path_superhero}, (res) => {
            let body = '';
            res.on('data', (d) => { body += d;});
            res.on('end', () => {
                // console.log("BODY:", body);
                let output = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(output);

            });
            res.on('error', (error) => {
                console.log(`Error while calling the API ${error}` );
            });
        });
    });
  }
```

I am using Actions SDK and the error thrown to me after calling this function is

> No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?

And the function in which I am calling this function is

```
  superhero.intent('superherocard', (conv, {superhero_entity}) => {
    superHero_with_name(superhero_entity).then((output)=>{
        if(output.response === 'success'){
            var super_name = output.results[0].name ;

            // Assigned values to all the variables used below this comment

            conv.ask("Here's your Superhero");
            conv.ask(new BasicCard({
                text: `Your SuperHero is the mighty **${super_name}**.  \n**INTELLIGENCE** *${intelligence}*  \n**STRENGTH** *${strength}*  \n**SPEED** *${speed}*  \n**DURABILITY** *${durability}*  \n**POWER** *${power}*  \n**COMBAT** *${combat}*`,
                title: super_name,
                subtitle: super_publisher,
                image: new Image({
                    url: image_superhero,
                    alt: super_name,
                }),
            }));

            conv.ask(text_1);

            conv.ask(new Suggestions(itemSuggestions));

        } else{
            conv.ask('Sorry, I cannot find the superhero you are finding! But you can become one by helping and motivating people.');
        }
        return console.log("superHeroCard executed");
    }).catch(()=> {
        conv.ask('Sorry, I cannot find the superhero you are finding! But you can become one by helping and motivating people.');
    });
  });
```

I am unable to find the error as I am returning the Promise but the intent handler is unable to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the Intent Handler *is* reading it, but it isn't *returning* it.

If you are doing async calls, your handler **must** return a Promise that will resolve when the async portion is done. If you are not doing async calls, then you don't need to return a promise - since the handler dispatcher doesn't need to wait for anything before it sends back a reply. If you are doing an async call, a Promise indicates to the dispatcher that it needs to wait for the Promise to be fully resolved before it can return the response that you've set.

In your case, you can probably adjust the first two lines of the handler to return the Promise that is returned by the function call and `then()` chain. Possibly something like:

```
superhero.intent('superherocard', (conv, {superhero_entity}) => {
  return superHero_with_name(superhero_entity).then((output)=>{
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank You once again for answering the question. But I'm still confused.
How just the normal conv.ask or conv.close works in an intent handler without returning anything and why function call is not working in the intent handler which is returning a promise.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm not sure what you mean by "why function call is not working in the intent handler". It *is* working, just that the handler returns the information before it finishes working. If you're still not clear, or something is still behaving that isn't expected, I suggest you open up a new question clarifying what you're encountering.